# Include html or php at beginning of each page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, fpm

I need insert some code or file (banner) to every web site using .htaccess on php7.3-fpm.

File .htaccess.

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
# Apache 2.4.10+ can proxy to unix socket
#SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
</FilesMatch>
```

I tried add

```
SetEnv PHP_VALUE 'auto_prepend_file "/var/www/html/test/banner.php"'
```

or

```
php_value auto_prepend_file "/dir/path/banner.php"
```

but nothing worked. Is possible to do this via .htaccess file, or I must set it in configuration file of php-fpm?

Thanks.

Comment: If the file contains any output (HTML/JS etc), then it's a really bad idea to prepend it to all files. Remember that if you do, you won't be able to set any headers in your code (like redirecs, sessions etc) since headers must be set _before_ any output at all. Also, the code won't be located inside the `<html></html>`-tag where it should be. IMHO, your application should handle the inclusion of the code, not the web server.

Comment: Why not just use PHP to include into a header.php file which you then use across your site? You can then have multiple header.php files and include which one you need depending on whether you want this to be included etc.

Comment: @Dammeul Thanks, but problem is, that I have many websites in this folder and still adding sites, so single add include to every header of page is not effective.